# Descriptor.value is undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a validation decorator follow by Typescript's docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators

So now I apply to my project .
Here is my validation.decorators.ts file :

```html
import "reflect-metadata";

const checkCapitalMetadataKey = Symbol("CheckCapital");

export function nameBeginWithCapital(
  target: Object,
  propertyKey: string | symbol,
  parameterIndex: number
) {
  let existingCapitalParameters: number[] =
    Reflect.getOwnMetadata(checkCapitalMetadataKey, target, propertyKey) || [];
  existingCapitalParameters.push(parameterIndex);
  Reflect.defineMetadata(
    checkCapitalMetadataKey,
    existingCapitalParameters,
    target,
    propertyKey
  );
}

export function validate(
  target: any,
  propertyName: string,
  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) {
  console.log(target, propertyName, descriptor);
  // let method = descriptor.value;
  // descriptor.value = function () {
  //   let capitalParameters: number[] = Reflect.getOwnMetadata(
  //     checkCapitalMetadataKey,
  //     target,
  //     propertyName
  //   );
  //   if (capitalParameters) {
  //     for (let parameterIndex of capitalParameters) {
  //       if (!arguments[parameterIndex].match(/^[A-Z].*/)) {
  //         throw new Error("Does not start with an uppercase letter!");
  //       }
  //     }
  //   }

  //   return method!.apply(this, arguments);
}
export function enumerable(value: boolean) {
  return function (
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) {
    console.log(target, propertyKey, descriptor);
    // descriptor.enumerable = value;
  };
}
```

And my app.ts file

```html
import {
  nameBeginWithCapital,
  validate,
  enumerable,
} from "./validation.decorators";

abstract class TodoComponent<T extends HTMLElement, U extends HTMLElement> {
  templateElement: HTMLTemplateElement;
  hostElement: T;
  element: U;
  constructor(templateId: string, hostId: string, isRenderAtStart: boolean) {
    this.templateElement = document.getElementById(
      templateId
    )! as HTMLTemplateElement;
    this.hostElement = document.getElementById(hostId)! as T;
    const importNode = document.importNode(this.templateElement.content, true)!;
    this.element = importNode.firstElementChild as U;
    this.render(isRenderAtStart);
  }
  render(isRenderAtStart: boolean) {
    this.hostElement.insertAdjacentElement(
      isRenderAtStart ? "afterbegin" : "beforeend",
      this.element
    );
  }
}

class TodoList extends TodoComponent<HTMLDivElement, HTMLDivElement> {
  constructor() {
    super("todo-list", "app", false);
  }
}

class TodoInput extends TodoComponent<HTMLDivElement, HTMLFormElement> {
  todoInput: HTMLInputElement;
  typeInput: HTMLSelectElement;
  buttonInput: HTMLButtonElement;
  constructor() {
    super("form-input", "app", true);
    this.todoInput = this.element.querySelector(
      ".todo-input"
    )! as HTMLInputElement;
    this.typeInput = this.element.querySelector(
      ".form-select"
    )! as HTMLSelectElement;
    this.buttonInput = this.element.querySelector(
      ".form-button"
    )! as HTMLButtonElement;
  }
  getInput() {}
  @validate
  submitHandler(@nameBeginWithCapital a: string) {
    console.log(a);
  }
  @enumerable(true)
  test() {}
}

const todoInput = new TodoInput();
const todoList = new TodoList();
```

When i print descriptor of decorator . The value of this in enumrable and validate is undefined .
Any thoughts about what it could be? Thanks!

Comment: Actually when I run the example on ts-node . It works . But i dont know why when i compile to browser it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try it on your console
`tsc index.ts --target ES5 -w --experimentalDecorators`

Comment: Why does this work?